# Javascript - multiply elements in an array by their position

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I multiply the elements in an array by their positions in the array?

For example,

I want to take the elements in this array

```
var multiply = [2, 4, 6, 7]
```

and essentially come out with (`2*1+4*2+6*3+7*4`).

I understand that I need to use a for loop but I don't know how to write it to get that result.

Thank you!

Comment: So how do you loop over an array? How do you add a number to another number and store the result into a variable?

Comment: You need to try some code before you can ask here. Stack Overflow is for help, not homework answers.

Comment: `var arr = [2, 4, 6, 7], multiplied = arr.map((v,i) => v * (i+1)), sum = multiplied.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this, but try to understand how it works:
I have replaced the old values in the array.

So `multiply` changed into the new values in this example.

```js
var multiply = [2, 4, 6, 7];

multiply.forEach(function(e, i) {
  multiply[i] = e * ++i;
})

document.write(JSON.stringify(multiply)); // output: [2,8,18,28]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
multiply.map(function(v, i){
  return v * (i+1);
});
```

You can assign it to a variable or do whatever you need with this (since a new array is returned).